# How do I edit the background of Axis labels in my plot?

Tags: bugs, output-formatting

I'm using the standard report stylesheet in *Mathematica* and when I output a plot, I've set it up so that I get a white background, however the axis labels still have a gray background. How do I change it to white? Here is a small example (you have to change your stylesheet to *StandardReport*):

```
Plot[Sqrt[x], {x, 0, 10},
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.025], Red},
 AxesLabel -> {"Prob[Drug,X]", "Prob[Drug,XgivenPos]"},
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/2, Background -> White
]
```

[image]

Comment: `LabelStyle -> Directive[Blue, Bold, Background -> White]`

Comment: I don't have this problem in version 7 under Windows.  Your input produces this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wwDJF.png

Comment: Mma 8.0 shows the same picture as @Mr.Wizard's

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Hmm, in Linux under *Mathematica* version 9.0.1 I get the exact same behavior as the OP.

Comment: Using Mathematica 9.0.1 on OSX here...

Comment: I am using v12.2.0, and the problem seems to have been resolved. It might have been resolved as early as v10.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could set the `LabelStyle` option in every plot or globally for all `Plot`'s

```
SetOptions[Plot, LabelStyle -> Directive[Background -> White]]
```

This should work.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly. I'll upvote as soon as I get more rep.