# How to prevent Grid Background from overriding Graphics Background

Tags: graphics, bugs, output-formatting, grid-layouts

I have plots with custom `PlotMarkers` that I need to display in a `Grid` with other information.  When the `Grid` is given a `Background` option

- The custom `PlotMarkers`are given the `Grid` background and it over prints other markers
- The axis labels and plot area are given the `Grid` background even if an explicit `Background` option has been given for the plot.

#### Plot outside of the grid

```
p =
 ListPlot[{{{1, 1}}, {{2, 1}}, {{3, 1}}},
  PlotMarkers -> Graphics /@ {
     Circle[{0, 0}, Scaled[.1]],
     Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.1]],
     Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.1], {0, 4}]},
  ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

#### Plot in a `Grid` with `Background` option

```
Grid[{{p}},
 Background -> LightBlue]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here the markers have been given the `Grid` `Background` option. Their background also over prints adjacent markers.

#### Plot with `Background` option in a `Grid` with `Background` option

```
Grid[{{Show[p, Background -> Pink]}},
 Background -> LightBlue]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The horror!  Even by explicitly setting the plot's `Background` option `Grid` still hijacks the background.

How do I stop `Grid` `Background` from overriding both the plot's and the custom `PlotMarkers` backgrounds?

Version 11.1.0 with Win 7 Ent

CASE:3890272

Comment: This seems like a bug. Try `Grid[{{Graphics[Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.1]]]}}, Background -> LightBlue]`. It comes out white, but if you move the cursor up, it becomes blue. I assume you don't want `Rasterize`?

Comment: This also seems platform dependent.  I get different results on Windows using 11.1.0.

Comment: @Stitch Correct. I do not want `Rasterize`.

Comment: Reported to WRI. CASE:3890272

Comment: I have since discovered  that I can wrap the plots in a `Pane` or `Panel` to protect the backgrounds from Grid.

Comment: Somewhat related: [(22279)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22279/121), [(83190)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83190/121), [(85521)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/85521/121)

Comment: I see you already found `Pane` as a solution before I posted.  Next time please consider self-answering rather than leaving a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find that often [`Pane`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pane.html) is effective in preserving the size and style of Graphics that are undesirably changed.

```
gp = Pane @ Show[p, Background -> Pink];

Grid[{{gp, Spacer[0]}, {Spacer[0], gp}}, Background -> LightBlue]
```

[image]

Other examples:

- [Hyperlink shrink the image, how to make the image become original size](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39149/hyperlink-shrink-the-image-how-to-make-the-image-become-original-size/39158#39158)
- [Inconsistent image sizing with Grid and Row?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72573/inconsistent-image-sizing-with-grid-and-row/72587#72587)

Answer (score 3):

What you have encountered looks like a bug to me. You might use `GraphicsGrid` as a work-around.

```
plot =
  ListPlot[{{{1, 1}}, {{2, 1}}, {{3, 1}}},
    PlotRangePadding -> {{Scaled[.15], Scaled[.15]}, Automatic},
    PlotMarkers -> 
      Graphics /@ 
        {Circle[{0, 0}, Scaled[.1]], 
         Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.1]], 
         Disk[{0, 0}, Scaled[.1], {0, 4}]},
   Background -> Pink,
   ImageSize -> Small]
```

[image: plot]

```
Grid[{{plot, " "}, {" ", plot}}, Background -> LightBlue]
```

[image: grid]

But with `GraphicsGrid`

```
GraphicsGrid[{{plot, " "}, {" ", plot}}, Background -> LightBlue]
```

[image: ggrid]

Comment: I will report to WRI.

Comment: `GraphicsGrid` is not viable since the grid has formatted text and makes good use of a few of the formatting options.   I have discovered that I can wrap the plots in a `Pane` or `Panel` to protect the backgrounds.